# Cannot read property error in Admob Native Ads

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to implement a native ad in my app. I have completed all of the steps. I have added layouts for ad_app_install.xml, ad_content.xml. And this is my code for requesting the native ad:

```
AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110");
        AdLoader adLoader = builder.forAppInstallAd(new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd ad) {
                // An app install ad loaded successfully, call this method again to
                // load the next ad.
                mNativeAds.add(ad);
                loadNativeAd(adLoadCount + 1);

            }
        }).forContentAd(new NativeContentAd.OnContentAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onContentAdLoaded(NativeContentAd ad) {
                // A content ad loaded successfully, call this method again to
                // load the next ad.
                mNativeAds.add(ad);
                loadNativeAd(adLoadCount + 1);
            }
        }).withAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // A native ad failed to load. Call this method again to load
                // the next ad in the items list.
                Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                        + " load another.");
                loadNativeAd(adLoadCount + 1);
            }
        }).build();
```

I am using the dummy ID for Admob. But every time I run my application, I am getting the error `I/Ads: Received log message: <Google:HTML> Cannot read property 'tracking_urls_and_actions' of undefined`
I have searched this error ut I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the AdMob codelab on a fresh emulator with Play Services I got this error also. Running on a real device didn't result in the error.